# MacBook Pro M3 date time in macOS Sonoma (14.2.1) all messed up after battery went to dead, how to fix automatic time?

Tags: macos, laptop, battery, date-time

My MacBook Pro M3 battery died on Friday Jan 19, 2024. The system is running macOS Sonoma (14.2.1). Then here's what happened:

1. Opened computer today on Monday Jan 22 around 9am.
2. Date time said Friday Jan 19th around 5pm.
3. I restarted my computer.
4. At the password screen it said March 30th (I don't know 2023 or 2024).
5. I logged in, and date time said Nov 13th 2023.
6. No links worked in the browser.
7. I manually set the date time to Jan 22nd.
8. The browser worked.

I imagine I am awaiting a host of other problems not having the date sync automatically. Any way I can fix this without having to factory reset my computer and lose all my data?

```
Operating System:
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Platform         : darwin
Distro           : macOS
Release          : 14.2.1
Codename         : macOS Sonoma
Kernel           : 23.2.0
Arch             : arm64
Hostname         : MacBook-Pro
Codepage         : UTF-8
Build            : 23C71

System:
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Manufacturer     : Apple Inc.
Model            : Mac15,6

CPU:
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Manufacturer     : Apple
Brand            : M3 Pro
Stepping         : 4
Speed            : 2.4
Cores            : 12
PhysicalCores    : 12
PerformanceCores : 6
EfficiencyCores  : 6
Processors       : 1
Socket           : SOC
```

[image]

Comment: I understand that these funky dates appeared with automatic time/date turned on, right?

Comment: Yeah the problem occurred when the datetime was set to automatically set, so I turned it off to fix it.

Comment: @Lance Does the MacBook Pro have network access? It has to sync with `time.apple.com` so it needs a network connection.

Comment: Yes I think, it was connecting to wifi no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot shows “Set time and date automatically” as disabled.

Switch it on (flick it to the right) and it should fix it.

[image]

It should look something like this when enabled; note I use dark mode thus why the image looks “darker” than your original screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I disabled that on purpose to fix the issue, let me try and turn it back on then...

Comment: @Lance So is this fixed?

Comment: It was fixed by resetting the time manually, but I don't think there was a "solution" haha. I was hoping to solve it permanently in a nice way.

Comment: @Lance Odd. So checking “Set time and date automatically” had no effect? Even now after it’s fixed?

Comment: No effect, I turned automatic back on, and things are still working, but initially I have to turn it off then on again I guess.